# Camel, Spring, OSGI: Is there a way to specify the stop method?

Tags: spring, osgi, apache-camel

I'm running a Camel Spring OSGI application. The Camel context is initialized through Spring.
When the bundle stops, I need to do some clean-up activities, like de-registering the message listener. How do I do that? Is there a method I can override? I understand that an OSGI bundle must provide the activator start and stop methods but my understanding also is that the Camel/Spring/OSGI framework overrides these methods.

My beanx.xml:

```
<beans>
  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="outboundBuilder" />
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

My java code:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() {
           .....
    }
}
```

Comment: DisposableBean? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html?is-external=true

Comment: This blog http://kevinboone.net/karafcameltest.html show you how to start a camel route inside a OSGI bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand a little on the answer of Bilgin Ibryam which is correct.

Camel has the ability to apply a policy to a route. This Policy controls routes at runtime. This will allow you to do custom logic at certain events of the route life time.

**Implementing a route policy.**

It is rather simple declare a new class which extends RoutePolicySupport then override the methods you are interested in.

```
public class MyRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport{

    @Override
        public void onStart(Route route) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(route);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStop(Route route) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop(route);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onExchangeBegin(route, exchange);
    }


}
```

Now use the route in your routebuilder configure() method like this:

```
 RoutePolicy policy = new MyRoutePolicy();
 from("timer://blah")
   .routeId("Test1").routePolicy(policy)
   .setBody().constant("A Message Like Hello World")
   .to("mock:meh");
```

If you were just using a Spring XML with a route then add the following:

```
<bean id="policy" class="MyRoutePolicy"/>


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route id="foo" routePolicyRef="MyRoutePolicy">
     <from uri="timer://blah"/>
     <setBody><constant>A Message Like Hello World</constant></setBody>        
     <to uri="mock:meh"/>
   </route>
 </camelContext>
```

Comment: Using the routebuilder configure() set up you suggest above results in the following exception:

    com.ctc.wstx.exc.WsTxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'A' (code 70) in prolog; expected '<'

Seems like XML or HTML is expected here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Camel [Route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) and write your code to cleanup resource when the route is about to stop or be removed from the context.