# How can I execute a Camel route on shutdown only?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a Camel 2.13.1 application which uses an external web service which I access through the CXF component. I use the startupOrder attribute of the Spring XML route element to ensure that a call is made to the Login operation of the web service in a route I've set up to be called once at startup (using the timer component).

When my application is shutting down I want Camel to call the web service and execute the logout operation but I can't see a good way of doing this. I'm using the Spring DSL at the moment and am looking into the org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownStrategy interface as my only hope but will I be able to execute a route that contains my CXF producer from it? Can't see how at the moment.

Looking for some options and would prefer to use the Spring DSL to specify the route like so:-

```
    <route id="logoutFromWebServiceOnShutdownRoute">
        <from uri="direct:logoutFromWebServiceOnShutdown" />
        <process ref="prepareWebServiceLogoutProcessor" />
        <to uri="cxf:bean:webServiceEndpoint?defaultOperationName=logout" />
        <process ref="webServiceLogoutResponseProcessor" />
    </route>
```

Just need to know how to call it on shutdown only! I'm running Camel as a WAR.

Comment: Using the route policy: See this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809040/camel-spring-osgi-is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-stop-method/23817812#23817812

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the route policy but can't get it working. I need the route in question to run once only on shutdown and can't see how that can be accomplished using the route policy.

Instead, I've utilised Spring by including a destroy-method attribute on a bean which calls my Logout code.

```
<bean class="com.chris.MyAuthenticationManager" destroy-method="logout" />
```

This runs after Camel has shut down and allows me to run the code only once. The down side is that I can't use Camel to logout and my login code is different to my logout code. However, it works and is now stable.