# How to Aspect a whole camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel, aspectj

Essentially, I'd like to aspect a whole camel route, so that I can grab the payload at the start and the end.

Now, I know I can just aspect the main "doing" class in the middle, not pulling it from a queue and placing it on the disk at the end. And this is fine for a simple route, not one that has many "doing" classes.

But is there a way to tie up the start and end of a route, without putting this into the route?

I have got a lot of routes and I'd like to keep them as clean of logging code as possible.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809040/camel-spring-osgi-is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-stop-method/23817812#23817812

Comment: I think you mean "advise", not "aspect".  Can you show a code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Use the interception possibilities of Camel as described [here](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html):

- `intercept` that intercepts each and every processing step while routing an Exchange in the route.
- `interceptFrom` that intercepts incoming Exchange in the route.
- `interceptSendToEndpoint` that intercepts when an Exchange is about to be sent to the given Endpoint.

In your case the second and third possibility may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got two choices:

1. Add a wiretap at the start and end of each route. See http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html. This obviously means editing the routes but is simple easy and it only two lines per route.
2. Use RouteDefinition.adviceWith to dynamically add an interceptor. See http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html. I've not seen this used outside testing but I don't see any reason why you can't use it in live code.